# Localization is not working after publishing ASP.NET Core App

Tags: localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core and I am using Portable Object Localization.
My localization is working fine but after publishing my app, the localization is not working. I want to publish my web app to a folder. I defined (ps, en, prs-Af) localizations but I get the below folders.

[image]

This is properties of of one of po files:

[image]

Comment: It may help to reproduce the error if you could share the properties of the po file

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that visual studio did not publish the localization files. I manually selected the files and chose the publish selected files from the context menu. Now it is working fine.